# Form not updating in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a edit button in a form, when user clicks on the edit button, and edit the form and clicks on save. It gets updated. But when the user reloads the page, it does not update the page. So, here is my code below. All I want is when user edits the text in the form, there text gets updated even they reload the page. (Like, I want the JSON file gets that request too, if possible). Thanks in advance.

```
    <div class="list-view">
  <form>
    <fieldset ng-disabled="inactive">

  <legend>Basic Info</legend>

  <b>First Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.first">
  <br>
  <b>Last Name:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.last">
  <br>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <input type="email" ng-model="people.email">
  <br>
  <b>Phone:</b>
  <input type="num"  ng-model="people.phone">
  <br>
  <b>Website:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.website">
  <br>
  <b>Education:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.education">
  <br>
  <b>Education Year:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.year">

  <br>
  <legend>Address</legend>

<b>Street:</b>
  <input type="text" ng-model="people.street">
  <br>
  <b>City:</b>
    <input type="text" ng-model="people.city">
    <br>
    <b>State:</b>
      <input type="text" ng-model="people.state">
      <br>
      <b>Zip:</b>
        <input type="text" ng-model="people.zip">
    <br>
    </fieldset>
    <button type="button" class="edit" ng-show="inactive" ng-click="inactive = !inactive">
          Edit
        </button>
    <button type="submit" class="submit" ng-show="!inactive" ng-click="save()">Save</button>



</form>
```

> app.js

```
    var app = angular.module("MyLab", ['ngRoute']);



app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.inactive = true;



});

$scope.save = function() {
  $scope.people.push($scope.people.name);
}
```

> Controller

```
        app.controller('MyController',['$scope', 'people', '$routeParams',
function($scope, people, $routeParams) {
  people.success(function(data) {
    $scope.people = data[$routeParams.id];

    $scope.save = function() {

      return people.editPeople()
      .then(function(data){
        $scope.datas = data.data; 
      })

    }


  });
}]);
```

> Json file

```
    [
  {
    "id": "0",
    "first": "John",
    "last": "Doe",
     "title": "Family",
    "date": "Joined 4/2/17",
    "email": "jdoe@email.com",
    "phone": "555-555-5555",
    "website": "www.google.com",
    "education": "Harvard",
    "year": "2008",
    "street": "123 Main Street",
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "state": "CA",
    "zip": "1234567"


  },

]
```

> index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyLab">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />



  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
          <h3>My Page</h3>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="main">
      <div class="container">
          <div ng-view>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

      <script src="js/MyController.js"></script>




  </body>
</html>
```

> Grabbing json

```
     app.factory('people', ['$http', function($http) {
  var services = {
    editPeople : editPeople
  }
  return services
  function editPeople() {

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "people.json",
        data: {
          people: $routerParams.id
        },
       headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

    })

  }
```

Comment: Where your `$scope.people.name` of you ? And push is method of `array` . I think `$scope.people` of you is object

Comment: and yes it is an object. BUT, can you show me of how to apply the save() or update() method to my code.

Comment: Can you provide  full code ?

Comment: which part you need ?

Comment: that is my full code above

Comment: what is `people.success` and `routeParams.id` of you

Comment: is when the user clicks on a particular user it goes to that type of user details after. For example: if i click on john it will go to john's detail page.

Comment: You use ajax to get data right ? Can you show me the code you get Json file and display in html

Comment: I need the code you get it and display in html . Can you provide it.

Comment: how about now? is it helpful?

Comment: no i dont need it . I need the code you get JSON file and use `ng-repeat`  or something to showing it in html

Comment: You can not update a json file without using a server-side language . And if you using ng-repeat to show data , It's not update

Comment: oh okay. can you show how to update the text prior to my code above?

Comment: I dont know exactly what does you mean . But if you want update the view , you can use ajax and send `$scope.people` to server and update it

Comment: can you show me an example prior to my code above?

Answer (score 1):

Here is example for update . You can use ajax to it . For example I use php in server-side

```
    .factory('people',...)
     var services = {
           editPeople : editPeople
}
      return services
     function editPeople(){
     $http({
                method: "POST",
                url: "model/update.php",
                data: {
                 people:$routeParams.id
                     },
               headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }

                })
      }
```

In ctrl

```
$scope.save = function(){
   return people.editPeople()
      .then(function(data){
         $scope.datas = data.data;
})
}
```

And display in html

```
ng-repeat ="data in datas"
{{data.name}}
```

Comment: this should be in app.factory or in my app.js?

Comment: It you want use factory I will update it . And this code above is in controller . `$scope.save` is ng-click of button save of you

Comment: can you please update in factory, so I can see how this works.

Comment: apply to my app.factory above, if you can please

Comment: No you can't update it with out server-side language like php or python

Comment: BUT, I don't want to use php or python though. isnt it there a way to update with json/ajax

Comment: No , you cant do it . If with out server-side language , it's not update when you refresh page

Comment: I'm glad for help :)